# constructor with generic parameters

Tags: generics, dart

since recently it is possible to create methods with generic methods
e.g.:

```
class Grid2<T> {
  static Grid2<T> fromLanes<L, T>(List<L> lanes, T generator(L element, int x, int z)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

but it would be way nicer to have the same as a named constructor like this (syntax failure) - is this possible?

```
class Grid2<T>
  Grid2.fromLanes<L>(List<L> lanes, T generator(L element, int x, int z)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently not supported, but there is an open issue with some discussion

**Support generic arguments for (named) constructors**
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26391

Answer (score 0):

```
class ArrayList1<T> {
  T name;
  ArrayList1(T name) {
  this.name = name;
  }
}

void main() {
  ArrayList1<String> obj = new ArrayList1<String>("hello");
  print(obj.name);
}
```

Comment: While this code might be the correct solution, you need to provide some explanation of why or how this solves the problem.

Comment: You can create the constructor like this for the generics. But it doesn't restrict you to pass only string to the constructor i mean you can also pass int and it works fine. I don't know why it is happing.

Comment: Now, why don't you right that in the answer itself?

Comment: because i haven't implemented the constructor. I have just checked assigning the integer value to the String and it was giving me error.